# mi slideshow se monta a mi menu en HTML

Tags: html, css3

Estoy desarrollando una página web. Esta tiene un menú y debajo del mismo hay un slideshow pero en el momento de desplasarse hacia abajo el slideshow se sobrepone en el menú y no sé porqué pasa eso.

**ccs**

```css
CSS DEL MENU: 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fffffa;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: :hidden;
  background: #252932;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.weapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  line-height: 200px;
}

header nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

header nav a:hover {
  background: #f56f3A;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.header2 {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
}

.header2 .logo {
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.header2 nav {
  line-height: 100px;
}

.contenido p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  header .logo,
  header nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
  .header2 {
    height: auto;
  }
  .header2 .logo .header2 nav {
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}














css del slideshow:
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
 
body {
background:#f2f2f2;

}
 
.main {
width:90%;
max-width:1000px;
margin:20px auto;

}
 
.slides {
width:100%;

}
 
.slides img {
width:100%;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination {
background:#424242;
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination li {
float:left;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination li a {
display:block;
padding:13.5px 20px;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
background:#000;
}
 
.slides .active {
background:#000;
}
 
.slidesjs-navigation{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:13.5px 20px;
float:right;
}
```

```html
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DOCUMENT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="header.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="weapper">
      <div class="logo">
        Reynaldo.inc
      </div>


      <nav>
        <a href="#">INICIO</a>
        <a href="#">SERVICIOS</a>
        <a href="#">PROYECTOS</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACTOS</a>

      </nav>
    </div>


  </header>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="Galeria/balloon_sky_flight_sunset_clouds_119652_800x600.jpg">

      <img src="Galeria/piopio_new_zealand_mountains_rocks_grass_evening_119665_800x600.jpg">

      <img src="Galeria/singapore_building_night_city_119649_800x600.jpg">

      <img src="Galeria/sneakers_legs_red_mountains_119647_800x600.jpg">

      <img src="Galeria/traffic_lights_indicator_sign_119607_800x600.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src: "jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".slides").slidesjs({
        play: {
          active: true,

          effect: "slide",

          interval: 3000,

          auto: true,

          swap: true,

          pauseOnHover: false,

          restartDelay: 2500
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

  <section class="contenido weapper">


  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

header.js
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ){
        $('header').addClass('header2');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('header2');
    }
});
```

});

[image]

Comment: y el código? coloca el html y el css

Comment: Ya lo agregue , lo Había olvidado

Comment: el css que agregaste a que archivo corresponde? falta algún css agregar?

Comment: estan todos los css tanto del menu como del slideshow

Comment: agrega también ese

Comment: ya lo acabo de agregar

Comment: lo veo bien todo, lo unico es saber que tiene header.js que creo que es el ultimo archivo que falta agregar.

Comment: Esto parece un problema con el `z-index`

Comment: @WFgo  ya lo acabo de agregar

Comment: lo mismo pense del z-index pero el caso nose en que parte ponerlo

Comment: exacto, es un problema de z-index. agrega eso y debes agregar tambien un  top: 0; a la respuesta que te dio @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p2s49wqv/17/ fijate la parte ultima del css , ahi agregue el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Esto parece un problema con el orden de los elementos en tu página y debería poder solucionarse asignando los valores de `z-index` apropiados.

Intenta añadir un valor de `z-index` que sea alto al `header` (o a la clase `.header2` que es la que se agrega cuando se hace scroll en la página) para que quede por encima del slideshow:

```
.header2 {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es muy facil, es una cuestión de z-index.

Agrega a la clase `.main` un `position: relative; z-index: 1;` y al header un `z-index: 10` o 9, o 9999, lo importante es que sea mayor a 2.

Y ya, mira:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ){
        $('header').addClass('header2');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('header2');
    }
});
});
```

```css
CSS DEL MENU: 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fffffa;
  font-family: arial;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: :hidden;
  background: #252932;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.weapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .logo {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 50px;
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

header nav a:hover {
  background: #f56f3A;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.header2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header2 .logo {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.contenido p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.slides,
.slides *{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  header .logo,
  header nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .header2 {
    height: auto;
  }
  .header2 .logo .header2 nav {
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}














css del slideshow:
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
 
body {
background:#f2f2f2;

}
 
.main {
width:90%;
max-width:1000px;
margin:20px auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
 
.slides {
width:100%;

}
 
.slides img {
width:100%;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination {
background:#424242;
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination li {
float:left;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination li a {
display:block;
padding:13.5px 20px;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
 
.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
background:#000;
}
 
.slides .active {
background:#000;
}
 
.slidesjs-navigation{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:13.5px 20px;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="weapper">
      <div class="logo">
        Reynaldo.inc
      </div>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">INICIO</a>
        <a href="#">SERVICIOS</a>
        <a href="#">PROYECTOS</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACTOS</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/800/600?image=255">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/800/600?image=254">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/800/600?image=257">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/800/600?image=251">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/800/600?image=247">
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidesjs/3.0/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".slides").slidesjs({
        play: {
          active: true,
          effect: "slide",
          interval: 3000,
          auto: true,
          swap: true,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          restartDelay: 2500
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <section class="contenido weapper">


  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu hoja de estilo define una clase que tenga las medidas, colores y formatos que quieres para tu menú, y en tu página web siempre divide todo por divs.

Por ejemplo:

**En tu hoja de estilos define las clases que necesites:**

```css
.top-bar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  .top-bar .top-bar-left,
  .top-bar .top-bar-right {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Y en tu página web separa todo por divs:**

```html
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="top-bar-left"></div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu vertical medium-horizontal">
            <li><a style="font-weight:bold" href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-weight:bold" href="#">PAGES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    ...Aquí pon tu slideshow
</div>
```